# Proving an isomorphism using the isomorphism theorems

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, group-isomorphism

Is the following proof correct, or are certain steps illegal?

Suppose $f:G_1\to G_2$ is a surjective group isomorphism, $N_1\lhd G_1, N_2\lhd G_2$ normal subgroups, with $N_1=f^{-1}(N_2)$. Prove that $(G_1/N_1)\cong (G_2/N_2)$.

**Proof:**

As $f$ is surjective, we an use the first isomorphism theorem to get $G_1/\ker(f)\cong G_2$, which implies that $$(G_1/\ker f)/(N_1/\ker f)\cong G_2/(N_1/\ker f)$$

Using the first isomorphism theorem we also know that $$N_1/\ker (f)\cong f(N_1)=f(f^{-1}(N_2))=N_2$$

Combining this we can see that $(G_1/\ker f)/(N_1/\ker f)\cong G_2/(N_1/\ker f)\cong G_2/N_2$.

Using the third isomorphism theorem we have that:
$$ (G_1/\ker f)/(N_1/\ker f)\cong G_1/N_1$$

And from the last two lines we have $G_1/N_1\cong G_2/N_2$ $\tag*{$\Box$}$

Comment: Strictly speaking, $N_1/{\rm ker}(f)$ is a subgroup of $G_1/{\rm ker}(f)$ not $G_2$, whereas $f(N_1)=N_2$ is the subgroup of $G_2$ you mean so your first line is dubious, but this seems to be using the result you are trying to prove...

Answer (score 1):

It's basically correct. However,  some things you wrote requires proper justification or explanation. Namely,

- Show that $\ker f\lhd N_1$.
- How do you exactly mean $G_2/\, (N_1/\ker f) $?

For a more direct approach, consider the arising homomorphism $G_1\to G_2/N_2$.

Comment: What do you mean with $\ker f \leq N_1$? Cardinality or subset or normality? And I just mean the quotient, or is that only defined if the subgroup is normal? (So I have to point out that they're normal)

Comment: 1. As subsets, but then $\ker f$ will be automatically a normal subgroup of $N_1$,  so to make sense of $N_1/\ker f$. 2. The problem is that $N_1/\ker f$ lives in another group. Spell out how you mean this quotient, and then you'll be done.